# Linking to so library in gcc

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I will start by saying that I am new to gcc and makefiles. I have a .so file on the desktop (~/Desktop) called `lib.so`. I want to link my program (called myProgram) to it. What I wrote in my makefile is:

```
g++ myProgram.o -L ~/Desktop -l lib -o myProgram
```

When I run `make` I get an error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llib
```

I also tried `-l lib.so` and got the same error.
What is the correct way to link?

Comment: When you use `-l foo`, it looks for `libfoo.so`. So `-l lib` is looking for `liblib.so`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. You should write this as answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it find `lib.so`, since it doesn't follow that naming convention.

Comment: That's fine I changed the file's name to libBenjy.so and linked with Benjy and it worked.

Comment: To get more info on the error, ld's verbose mode helps, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16710047/ (the answer below fixes the most likely ones still)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Rename the file to `libsomething.so`, then use `-l something`. The linker automatically wraps the name with `lib` prefix and `.so` suffix (or `.a` suffix for static libraries).
2. Use the option `-l:lib.so`. When you prefix the name with `:`, the linker uses the name as given.

These are explained in the `ld` man page.

Comment: Another quick question, when running the application I get an error "Cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". How do I tell him to use load the library at runtime?

Comment: The directory should be in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.

Comment: For some reason I don't have an LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, but I'll stop hassling you.

Comment: You only need that variable if you want to find libraries in non-standard places.

Comment: You can add an rpath to the executable. This way when exe is executed will look in this path (in addition to LD_LIBRARY_PATH). You can add an rpath this way:

    gcc ....  -Wl,-rpath=/path/to/sharedlibrary/folder

Comment: suggest "-l:lib.so" without blank