# /usr/bin/ld cannot find lib files when compiling openCv matlab source

Tags: matlab, opencv, ubuntu

I am getting the following error when trying to compile openCV with the matlab module.

I just run $make in the realse folder that I created like in the [tutorial from opencv.org](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html?highlight=install%20ubuntu)

```
    [ 98%] Compiling Matlab source files. This could take a while...
    CMake Error at /home/alex/Downloads/opencv-master/modules/matlab/compile.cmake:47 (message):
    Failed to compile drawChessboardCorners: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find
      -lopencv_core

  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgproc

  (Removed alot of lines with lib files here)

  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status



      mex: link of ' "drawChessboardCorners.mexa64"' failed.
```

How do I fix the link error? Does it have something to do with matlab?

MATLAB 2013a
Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is related to MATLAB. The:

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find`

points probably to a missing path for the `opencv_core` library that the linker cannot find during compilation. See: [usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l<nameOfTheLibrary>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary)

If you are building manually you could add an `-L` option, e.g.,

`-L<path_to_opencv_core>` before the `-lopencv_core` or `-lopencv_imgproc`

to the command line build command. If you are using a CMake file, there may be an `${OPENCV_LIB_INSTALL_PATH}` (or something similar) that you can set, e.g., using `ccmake.`