# error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1

Tags: macos, rust

I have a **single** .rs file. When I compile it by `rustc test1.rs`, I get an error:

```
    error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1
note: cc '-m64' '-L' '/usr/local/Cellar/rust/1.0.0-alpha/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib' '-o' 'test1' 'test1.o' '-Wl,-force_load,/usr/local/Cellar/rust/1.0.0-alpha/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libmorestack.a' '-Wl,-dead_strip' '-nodefaultlibs' '/usr/local/Cellar/rust/1.0.0-alpha/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libstd-4e7c5e5c.rlib' '/usr/local/Cellar/rust/1.0.0-alpha/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libcollections-4e7c5e5c.rlib' '/usr/local/Cellar/rust/1.0.0-alpha/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libunicode-4e7c5e5c.rlib' '/usr/local/Cellar/rust/1.0.0-alpha/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/librand-4e7c5e5c.rlib' '/usr/local/Cellar/rust/1.0.0-alpha/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/liballoc-4e7c5e5c.rlib' '/usr/local/Cellar/rust/1.0.0-alpha/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/liblibc-4e7c5e5c.rlib' '/usr/local/Cellar/rust/1.0.0-alpha/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libcore-4e7c5e5c.rlib' '-L' '/usr/local/Cellar/rust/1.0.0-alpha/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib' '-L' '/Users/alex/Documents/projects/rust/.rust/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin' '-L' '/Users/alex/Documents/projects/rust/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin' '-lSystem' '-lpthread' '-lc' '-lm' '-lcompiler-rt'
note: ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/alex/Documents/projects/rust/.rust/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/alex/Documents/projects/rust/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin'
ld: can't open output file for writing: test1, errno=21 for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

error: aborting due to previous error


$ rustc --version
rustc 1.0.0-dev
```

I've seen some topic related to this one but none of them helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: No idea why this worked--I got this to go away by updating Rust

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your command `rustc test1.rs` the compiler infers the name of the executable should be `test1`. The linker tries to open this file so it can write the executable but fails with `errno=21` whose stringified version is "Is a directory".

This suggests you have a directory in your working directory called `test1` which is causing a conflict.

Comment: Spot on. I had a very similar problem, and this answer was helpful in narrowing down the error message.

Answer (score 77):

I was faced with **three problems** on Mac compiling Rust:

**First:** If you have any issue with writing files/dirs by `ld` just remove that files and try to recompile. I don't know why, but on Mac this issue happens time to time.

**Second:** If you have other `ld` errors (not about file access): try to add the following sections to your `~/.cargo/config` (if you don't have this file feel free to create):

```
[target.x86_64-apple-darwin]
rustflags = [
  "-C", "link-arg=-undefined",
  "-C", "link-arg=dynamic_lookup",
]

[target.aarch64-apple-darwin]
rustflags = [
  "-C", "link-arg=-undefined",
  "-C", "link-arg=dynamic_lookup",
]
```

**Third:** Sometimes your Mac lack of some dev tools/dependencies. Install the most important of them automatically with the command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Whenever you update the Mac with the new major mac release, usually the XCODE toolchain gets outdated that's the root cause of getting this error. Reinstalling the latest Xcode most of the time fixed the issue.

Comment: The cargo config was the missing piece for me. Thank you!

Comment: thank you so much @denis. This saved me a ton of hours. Cargo config is the deal here

Comment: Cargo config solved my error, thank you!

Comment: The config worked for me too!

Comment: Option third solved my problem. I tried the first option, there it showed problem with xcode. Then tried 3 option

Comment: The config worked for me. thanksss alot

Comment: what should be the extension of carg/config file

Comment: no extension needed, `.cargo/config`

Comment: Thank you @DenisKolodin ! You also saved me many hours, changing `.cargo/config` also worked for me <3 <3

Comment: I also had to run `sudo xcodebuild -license` after `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 12):

If you have `note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3`

then install `libsqlite3-dev`:

`$ sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev`

This works on **Rust 1.53.0, Linux Mint 20.2(based on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)**

Comment: This is not just specific to sqlite3.
In general, if you have a compilation error ending with somthing like `**note** /usr/bin/ld cannot find -l<nameOfTheLibrary>` refer to the solutions here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/16710047/11565176

.In my case I was missing the library all together and so this answer helped me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42339395/11565176

Comment: If you are having this error on a linus or wsl2 ubuntu, this works fine. I had the error when trying to install sqlite with diesel

Answer (score 10):

If you have a MacBook M1(x) with ARM processor you need to install rust from rustup https://sourabhbajaj.com/mac-setup/Rust/

When you run `rustup-init`, use the customize option to change `aarch64-apple-darwin` to `x86_64-apple-darwin`

Then you can add the following to `.cargo/config.toml` or `.cargo/config` (either is fine)

```
[target.x86_64-apple-darwin]
rustflags = [
  "-C", "link-arg=-undefined",
  "-C", "link-arg=dynamic_lookup",
]
```

This solution was tested with Rust 1.54 and MacBook M1

I was able to do a `cargo build --release` and generate a dylib file from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqLD22sIYMo

Comment: This is what worked for me on my M1.

Answer (score 10):

My rust project stopped building after updating my MacOS so this command fixed it for me

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently and I found out this solution that worked for me:

https://www.docker.com/blog/cross-compiling-rust-code-for-multiple-architectures/

On Running Rust on aarch64 I found out that libc6-dev-arm64-cross is need in order to compile rust successfully on aarch64.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm on a ubuntu22.04, I got error like following

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
...
note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.10: No such file or directory
```

I solved it by `sudo apt install python3.10-dev`