# OPEN: Fedora 22, 32 bit machine. Unable to install/build mysql-workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench, fedora

### **EDIT: See comments.**

<strike>.I am unable to launch mysql-workbench on my Fedora 22 machine. It is installed, or at least it seems so.</strike> Help is welcome.

```
[root@localhost /]# dnf info mysql-community-bench
Nome        : mysql-community-bench
```

---

```
[root@localhost /]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.1.3-201.fc22.i686+PAE #1 SMP Wed Jul 29 20:36:37 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see installed MySQL Workbench, what you installed is MySQL benchmark (not Workbench). You can grab your MySQL Workbench rpm package from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: yes, shame on me. Still, i tried `rpm -Uvh mysql-workbench-community-6.3.4-1.fc22.src.rpm`, it seems to go thru, but I am not able to launch.

Comment: @mario: this is source package, you need to rebuild it to install, but insead you can download and install binary package (**mysql-workbench-community-6.3.4-1.fc22.x86_64.rpm**) from page I gave you

Comment: `# dnf install mysql-workbench-community-6.3.4-1.fc22.x86_64.rpm [...]

Error: package mysql-workbench-community-6.3.4-1.fc22.x86_64 is not installable`. I am on a 32 bit.

Comment: I am trying  `dnf   install mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.fc20.i686.rpm`, but i get `Error: nothing provides libctemplate.so.2 needed by mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.fc20.i686`.

Comment: @mario: ah, I didn't notice that is 32 bit platform, We do not provide 32bit packages for Linux (see http://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/workbench.html for details). You can build own Wb from scratch using source code.

Comment: Would the fc20 version work on F22? It seems it does not. Also, pls. suggest instruction on to build from source.

Comment: `rpmbuild --rebuild   --define='release 1' mysql-workbench-community-6.3.4-1.fc22.src.rpm` fails with msg `Cannot find /root/mysql-server/bin/mysql_config (MYSQL_CONFIG_PATH)`. Indeed `# locate mysql_config -> /etc/alternatives/mysql_config
/usr/bin/mysql_config  /usr/bin/mysql_config-32 /usr/bin/mysql_config_editor`. May I fix?

Comment: Fixed above by a symbolic link. But built still fails: `/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/mysql-workbench-community-6.3.4-src/library/grt/src/grtpp_grt.cpp:31:31: fatal error: cppconn/exception.h: No such file or directory   compilation terminated.`

Comment: i know why:  `C++ Connector detected: FALSE
-- C++ Connector version 1.1.5 or higher: FALSE` Fixed by  `dnf install mysql-connector-c++-1.1.6-linux-glibc2.5-x86-32bit.rpm`

Comment: Next, how do I fix  `/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/mysql-workbench-community-6.3.4-src/backend/wbpublic/grt/spatial_handler.cpp:20:0:
/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/mysql-workbench-community-6.3.4-src/backend/wbpublic/grt/spatial_handler.h:23:30: fatal error: gdal/ogrsf_frmts.h: No such file or directory`?

Comment: Yes, and gdal-devel too (to get `gdal/ogrsf_frmts.h`). Now I get `make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/root/linux-res-6.3/gdal/lib/libgdal.so', needed by 'backend/wbpublic/libwbpublic.so.6.3.4'.  Stop.`. How do I fix it? Thks.

Comment: that means usually you don't have a file `libgdal.so` available to make in this location, so set `gdal_dir` enviroment varaiable to point to proper location or make symlink that'll point to /root/linux-res-6.3/gdal/lib/libgdal.so

Comment: do you mean I need to mkdir `/root/linux-res-6.3/gdal/lib/` and symlink to `/usr/lib/libgdal.so`? Also, `mysql-workbench.spec` has `%define gdal_dir         $HOME/linux-res-6.3/gdal`. Why so? Should I change to some other dir?

Comment: Ok, it seems that to mkdir `/root/linux-res-6.3/gdal/lib/` and symlink to `/usr/lib/libgdal.so` helps to get a little further. Now it breaks with `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient`. What next?

Comment: Ok, thanks to [dcarrith](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary), I fixed the `ld` issue by a symlink. Now I get to 97% of built, but stiil something to overcome: `plugins/migration/CMakeFiles/wbcopytables-bin.dir/build.make:163: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.`. At the moment, I have not an idea on how to fix it. Help very welcome.

Comment: line 163 above is `plugins/migration/wbcopytables-bin: /bin/sh:\ /root/linux-res-6.3/usr/bin/iodbc-config:\ No\ such\ file\ or\ directory`. Do you see a typo?

Comment: to build wbcopytables you need iodbc, you can grab it from http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/iodbc/wiki/iODBC/Downloads, you'll also need pyodbc - https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/

Comment: libiodbc-3.52.7-8.fc22.i686, libiodbc-devel-3.52.7-8.fc22.i686, pyodbc-3.0.7-2.fc22.i686,  python3-pyodbc-3.0.7-2.fc22.i686? Let me try.

Comment: Almost there, but not quite; got to 100% but  `cp: cannot stat '/root/linux-res-6.3/cppconn-gpl/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.7*': No such file or directory`.  It seems I needed to create a number of subdirectories `root/linux-res-6.3/`, and symlink to appropriate files. Question is: for for how many  libraries? Is there a better way to learn than trial&error? I'll update.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but i gave another try. i fixed a few things, went further, but it still complains about `cannot stat '/root/linux-res-6.3/usr/lib/libiodbcadm.so*': No such file or directory`. Inn this case, I am not able to understand which package install `libiodbcadm.so`. Any idea?

Comment: If I remeber correctly, you need to install `libiodbc` package.

Comment: Nope, `Package libiodbc-3.52.7-8.fc22.i686 is already installed, skipping` `Package libiodbc-devel-3.52.7-8.fc22.i686 is already installed, skipping` and `locate libiodbc` does not return any `libiodbcadm`. Why so?

Comment: Is `libiodbcadm` related to the GTK+ Administrator? Does `iodbc` need to be built with `--enable-gui` (it seems so, see [here](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/iodbc/wiki/iODBC/IODBCRubyHOWTO))? Were provided binaries built so? How do I check? ps. Just to install `gtk+` and reinstall `libiodbc` and `libiodbc/devel` did not help.

Comment: It seems I run into a bug, or indeed more than one. Please see at [fedoraforum](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?p=1741365&posted=1#post1741365) and join discussion. Your help is welcome.  Thanks very much to Młlosz.
(Is there any hope to have a working 32bit version from mysql.com?)

Comment: @mario I read your thread on fedora forum - so you finally installed workbench 6.1.7 and now you have issue with blank result grid? did you try patch attached to bug link you posted? (this one http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74147)

Comment: i am not sure how. I guess from source, correct? Pls. point to me some instructions. By the way, why don't I see WB for F20 or higher at the [Fedora packages DB](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/mysql-workbench/)?

Comment: ***aarrgghh!*** I am trying to build `mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1.fc20.src.rpm` (patch above seems to help). But 6.1.7 calls - I guess - Lua5.1, I have installed Lua5.2 ages ago, which does not recognize `LUA_GLOBALSINDEX`, and built fails. To remove Lua5.2 does not seem easy: `# dnf remove lua > The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: dnf.`  ***aarrgghh!***

Comment: aarrgghh indeed. I've tried twice and still giving up. They give the source but it just feels like false hope. Like in the 3 hours long movie "Interstellar".

Answer (score 0):

What i have done to install **mysql-workbench** on my *Fedora 22 (64 bits)*,
was to install required libraries before :

```
sudo dnf install -y ctemplate tinyxml vsqlite++ python-paramiko
```

Then i downloaded the **mysql-workbench** *.rpm* here : https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/
*Fedora 22 (x86, 64-bit), RPM Package       6.3.4   17.4M*

and finally installed successfully the package.

**So maybe you could try instaling the Fedora 20 package after installing the required libraries above.**

Comment: In fact i guessed the required libraries by first trying to install the _.rpm_ and collecting the error messages one by one : missing library blabla ...

Comment: I am doing almost so, but I need to build from source, they don't offer binaries for 32 bit, and error messages are not always so clear.