# Unable to install json - Ubuntu 14.04 - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, heroku

```
gem install json
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150916-3216-1xudd6p.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [generator.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out
```

Hey. I'm trying to push to heroku but hit a dead end with this. First, there was the sqlit3 problem. Now, I'm unable to install json when I type bundle. What should I do now?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: install the gmp library?

Comment: possible duplicate of [usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l<nameOfTheLibrary>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary)

Comment: Thanks Marc B! It worked. Stuck with other heroku deployment problems now.

Comment: [JSON is built into Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/index.html). Why are you trying to reinstall it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem. You need to install `libgmp-dev`

Run `sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev` fix the problem.