# How can I share my SDL project easily?

Tags: c, linux, compilation, sdl-2

I want to share a SDL project with members of my group, so that they don't need to install any sdl packages in their computer. I compiled the source of sdl2, sdl2_image, sdl2_tff, and I took the static library.

I compile this way :

```
LDFLAGS = `./sdl2-config --static-libs --libs` -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2_gfx
```

sdl2-config produce this output :

```
-L/ -Wl,-rpath,libs/ -lSDL2 -Wl,--no-undefined -lm -ldl -lsndio -lpthread -lrt
-Llibs/ -Wl,-rpath,libs/ -lSDL2
```

And I have these files in my libs/ directory :

```
libSDL2.a      libSDL2_image.a        libSDL2_ttf-2.0.so.0.14.0*  libSDL2_ttf.la*
libSDL2_gfx.a  libSDL2_ttf-2.0.so.0@  libSDL2_ttf.a               libSDL2_ttf.so@
```

**My problem is, when my team tries to compile it in a OpenSuse distrib, they have this error :**

/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lsndio

Do you know what I did wrong, how can I fix it ?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary

Comment: @MonkeyShen I know that the linker is looking for libsndio, I have this library in my distrubution but in opensuse they don't have it. I am just looking for a easy way to share a sdl project.

Comment: maybe you should compile the lib yourself in OpenSuse?

Comment: Disable `sndio` in SDL (via option `-DSNDIO=OFF` or ccmake/cmake-gui) if you don't use it.

Comment: @keltar thanks you that works fine !