# Caffe compilation error on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, caffe, ubuntu-16.04

I think I pretty much followed all the instructions in:
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-Installation-Guide.

I still get the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:567: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3' failed
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3] Error
```

Has anyone come across this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l<nameOfTheLibrary>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install OpenBLAS? Try the following command and repeat the compillation process:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libopenblas-dev
```

If it fails, you could try compilling caffe with cmake.

From the build folder, do:

```
cmake -DBLAS=open ..
make all -j $(($(nproc) + 1))
make install
make runtest
```

You should provide the config file to better understand the links.