# "Cannot find -lfftw3_omp" error when compiling a third-party package. How to link the existing library?

Tags: python, makefile, anaconda, fftw

I'm trying to compile a third-party package on my Ubuntu 16.04 system in order to use it in Anaconda which is the default Python environment. When I run `make` the compilation stops with the following error:

```
/home/myname/anaconda3/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lfftw3_omp
/home/myname/anaconda3/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lm
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
Makefile:109: recipe for target '_shtns.so' failed
make: *** [_shtns.so] Error 1
```

It seems that Anaconda does not have access to the two libraries mentioned in the error message. The library fftw3_omp.so definitely exists in the folder `/home/myname/usr/lib`. I'm not sure what `-lm` is, though. How can I link the missing libraries correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l<nameOfTheLibrary>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary)

Comment: `-lm` is the standard math library.

Comment: For `-lxxx` to match, the library must be named `libxxx` (with the relevant library suffix).

Answer (score 2):

I got the similar error:

> /home/sfchen/anaconda3/envs/dlpy2/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lpthread
>   /home/sfchen/anaconda3/envs/dlpy2/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lc

and solved by follow steps.

1. find the root of the lib (e.g.  lpthread)

   > ld -lpthread --verbose

output like this:

```
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so failed
attempt to open //usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so failed
attempt to open //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a failed
attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so succeeded
opened script file //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so
opened script file //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 succeeded
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread_nonshared.a succeeded
libc.so.6 needed by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
found libc.so.6 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 needed by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
found ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 at //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address
```

2. From the 5th line above

`attempt to open //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so succeeded`

get the **path1** = `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so`

3. From the error message: `/home/sfchen/anaconda3/envs/dlpy2/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lpthread`

get the **path2** = `/home/sfchen/anaconda3/envs/dlpy2/compiler_compat/`

4. Last, input like this :

   > ln -s **path1 path2**

Specifically,

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so /home/sfchen/anaconda3/envs/dlpy2/compiler_compat/
```

that's all, hope it may be helpful!