# ld: cannot find lcom_err

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, ld

RELATED [usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l<nameOfTheLibrary>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary)

```
/bin/ld -Bshareable -hkadm5_hook_test.so.0 -o kadm5_hook_test.so main.so -R/usr/local/lib -L../../../lib -lkrb5 -lcom_err -lk5crypto -lkrb5support
```

OUTPUT

```
ld: error: cannot find -lcom_err
```

however, i see com_err .so under /lib

```
[]$ ls -la /lib | grep com_err
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 May 26  2017 libcom_err.so.2 -> libcom_err.so.2.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   15496 Oct 12  2012 libcom_err.so.2.1
```

what are the possible reasons for it not being able to find it?

--

## rpm -qa | grep com_err

```
libcom_err-1.41.12-22.el6.x86_64
libcom_err-devel-1.41.12-22.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: »» however, i see com_err .so under /lib «« : No `libcom_err.so` is shown ! Please install `libcom_err-devel`

Comment: @KnudLarsen com_err-devel is alreay installed