# Install python package PyTables 2.4 failure

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation

For some reason, I have to install PyTables 2.4 in Python 2.7, but there always are some problems that I can't solve.

It shows like below. I used Ubuntu OS. I have installed the HDF5 and set HDF5_DIR path.
[安装报错](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frEPN.png)

I don't know how to handle it. wish you guys can help me. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your hdf5 path is incorrect.
AFAIK, generally, the error `-l<libraryName>` occur when your symbolic link is broken. A solution is to `ld` the library in `verbose` mode:

```
 ld -l<libraryName> --verbose
```

to see where the OS look for library, and make correspond link
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) post (especially dcarrith's answer) for more details.

Hope this help!

Comment: It is the symbolic link's problem. After I reset the link, another problem occurred, it says that "Could't find the bzlib.h", what's the wrong?

Comment: Do you install libbz? Try `sudo apt-get install libbz2-1.0 libbz2-dev`

Comment: Actually, libbz has been installed. Is it the link problem? After I use pip to install, it shows like that.[![result](https://s1.ax1x.com/2018/06/13/CO7ojA.md.png)](https://imgchr.com/i/CO7ojA), Could you help me?

Comment: It's strange when you installed it but the output say it can't find bzlib. Great chance that there is something to do with your PATH. Have you tried to recheck your PATH? I suggest you do the following, not an elegant solution but it will work:  `1.` Find libbz in your system by using `find . -name "bzlib*"`  
`2.` Copy the output dir. Within a terminal session  `export PATH=/path/to/bzlib/:$PATH`. If you want the change to be permanent, add the `export` command to `~/.bashrc`. Tell me if you still have problem!

Comment: Thank you very mush. Firstly, I install tables2.4 in old conda environment. It always shows failure. Finally, I create a new conda environment. It works.