# How do I link to a library with g++?

Tags: compilation, g++, shared-libraries

I'm trying to compile a little test program with Open ALPR as described on https://github.com/openalpr/openalpr/wiki/Integrating-OpenALPR.
I've come up with something like:

```
#include <alpr.h>
#include <iostream>

int main (void) 
{
    alpr::Alpr openalpr("us", "/etc/openalpr/openalpr.conf");


    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

but I am unable to get it to compile. I've tried:
`g++ -Wall -l /usr/lib/libopenalpr.so test.cpp -o test` but I get
`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/usr/lib/libopenalpr.so`.
`/usr/lib/libopenalpr.so` does exist and links to `libopenalpr.so.2`, which also exists. What is the correct way to link to this library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l<nameOfTheLibrary>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary)

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found here:
[unable to compile with library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51462047/unable-to-compile-with-library)