# unable to compile with library

Tags: compilation, shared-libraries, linker, g++

I would like to experiment with the OpenALPR SDK and have written a little test program. The problem is, I can't get it to compile properly and I'm not sure why. Here's the [SDK documentation](http://doc.openalpr.com/sdk.html#c).

My source file looks like:

```
$ cat test.cpp 
#include <alpr.h>
#include <iostream>

std::string key =
"MyKey";

int main (void) 
{
    alpr::Alpr openalpr("us", "/etc/openalpr/openalpr.conf", "/usr/share/openalpr/runtime_data/", key);

    // Make sure the library loaded before continuing.  
    // For example, it could fail if the config/runtime_data is not found
    if (openalpr.isLoaded() == false)
    {
            std::cerr << "Error loading OpenALPR" << std::endl;
                return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I use the following command to compile and get the output:

```
$ g++ -Wall -lopenalpr test.cpp -o test
/tmp/ccGjLkrk.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0xc5): undefined reference to `alpr::Alpr::Alpr(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
test.cpp:(.text+0x134): undefined reference to `alpr::Alpr::isLoaded()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x18e): undefined reference to `alpr::Alpr::~Alpr()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x1ce): undefined reference to `alpr::Alpr::~Alpr()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x202): undefined reference to `alpr::Alpr::~Alpr()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x236): undefined reference to `alpr::Alpr::~Alpr()'
test.cpp:(.text+0x273): undefined reference to `alpr::Alpr::~Alpr()'
/tmp/ccGjLkrk.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x290): more undefined references to `alpr::Alpr::~Alpr()' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Just confirming my library is where it should be: `libopenalpr.so` is a symlink to `libopenalpr.so.2`.

```
$ locate libopenalpr.so
/usr/lib/libopenalpr.so
/usr/lib/libopenalpr.so.2
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Related: [Why does the order of '-l' option in gcc matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `gcc(1)` man page:

> ... the placement of the -l option is significant.
>
> [...]
>
> It makes a difference where in the command you write this option;
>              the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the
>              order they are specified.  Thus, `foo.o -lz bar.o` searches library `z`
>              after file `foo.o` but before `bar.o`.  If `bar.o` refers to functions in
>              `z`, those functions may not be loaded.

```
$ g++ -Wall test.cpp -lopenalpr -o test
```