# How to point to MPI lib path?

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, centos, mpi

My question is so simple but took me two days with no success. For installing a program (WRF model), I need to define MPI path. I already tried two ways:

```
setenv LDFLAGS -L$DIR/mpi/lib
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $LD_LIBRARY_PATH":""/home/32/bt305632/software/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/mpi/lib"
```

But it does not stop following error

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpifort /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmpi
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I am also aware of this response 
[usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l<nameOfTheLibrary>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary/34256630)

```
g++ -L/home/user/myDir -lxyz myprog.cpp -o myprog
```

But I do not know how to implement it for my case since I am using 
./configure and 
./compile

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Use `mpic++`...

Comment: I am newbie to these things. I tried to find out what you mean but I could not. Could you please explain how to do it?

Comment: I have to refer you to the manual of the MPI implementation you use. Stackoverflow is not a replacement for reading the manual.

Comment: `configure CC=mpicc CXX=mpicxx ...`