# Error when building simuLTE with MODE=release

Tags: omnet++, veins, simulte

In order to run the simulation faster, I am trying to build simuLTE in release mode as can be achieved for veins.

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~/simulte_veins/simulte$ make MODE=release
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/simulte_veins/simulte/src'
Creating shared library: ../out/gcc-release/src/liblte.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lINET
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lveins_inet
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:275: recipe for target '../out/gcc-release/src/liblte.so' failed
make[1]: *** [../out/gcc-release/src/liblte.so] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/simulte_veins/simulte/src'
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have tried appending ~/.bashrc with INET and veins_inet paths as observed from the MAKEFILE under lte/src/ in the following manner:

```
export veins_inet=$HOME/simulte_veins/veins-veins-4.6/subprojects/veins_inet/out/gcc-debug/src:$PATH   
export INET=$HOME/inet/out/gcc-debug/src:$PATH
```

I also tried updating $PATH directly by adding INET and veins_inet paths but to no avail.

Where am I going wrong?
Do I need to build INET and veins_inet in release mode before building lte?
I even tried building INET in MODE=release and I encountered the same error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lINET
```

I am using OMNeT++ 5.1.1;veins 4.6;sumo 0.30.0;simulte v1.0.1

Similar issue was raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary). However, I am not sure if I should try to link the .so file in their respective directories again to -lINET and -lveins_inet respectively. Can anybody advise me?

Comment: Using `make V=1` you can get the exact compiler command that failed. It looks like the libraries you want to link against cannot be found, did you set the `INET_PROJ` environment variable when building simuLTE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the build works for the debug version, but not for the release version, then you have not compiled release version libraries for INET and VEINS_INET. Go to their respective dirs and build those components, too.