# Troubles installing RMariaDB on CentOS

Tags: r, centos7

I need to install specific version on RMariaDB on CentOS. While installing it via command

```
install_version('RMariaDB', version='1.0.10', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

I have encountered a strange issue:

> /bin/ld: cannot find -lmariadb

So far I was unable to solve this. Tried installing several mariadb packages (i.e. mariadb-devel) on CentOS, but that does not resolved this issue. Can answer any question needed.

Comment: From https://github.com/r-dbi/RMariaDB: *"Installation from source on Linux or OS X currently requires Oracle's libmysqlclient or the more modern MariaDB Connector/C. The latter works best in version 2.3.4/3.0.3 or later, with older versions character and blob columns do not work reliably."* So ... `sudo yum install mysql-devel`.

Comment: But further research reveals: RMariaDB's issue [#113](https://github.com/r-dbi/RMariaDB/issues/113) suggested this was only fixable with a server-reinstall (ugh); and an older [#73](https://github.com/r-dbi/RMariaDB/issues/73) suggests ensuring that the OS is looking in the right place for the libraries, c.f., https://stackoverflow.com/q/16710047/3358272.

Comment: @r2evans You are correct. We have done some testing and found a root cause of this issue. Since you were correct with the devel package, I'm mentioning you in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @r2evans wrote in the comment. Correct answer to this would be installing mariadb/mysql devel package. Unfortunately this does not solve this issue, when MariaDB is installed from MariaDB10.repo
After some testing, this issue was solved after installing MariaDB5.5 from official repositories.

Comment: Frustrating that *this* is the only way known so far to resolve it. Glad you found a way-forward. Make sure to "accept" this answer when the system permits you to do so.