# lexbor C: How to correctly install and use on CentOS 7

Tags: c, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, centos7

**Goal:**

To correctly install and use [lexbor](https://github.com/lexbor/lexbor) on CentOS 7.

**Current output:**

When I go to compile a program using `lexbor` with the command `gcc example.c -liblexbor -std=c99 -o example` on `CentOS 7`, the following error is received:

```
[user@localhost]$ gcc example.c -liblexbor -std=c99 -o example
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -liblexbor
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Details:**

I installed `lexbor` for `CentOS 7` following the instructions [found at this link for CentOS 7.](https://lexbor.com/download/#centos) It seems that the linker cannot find the library. I ran the command `ldconfig -p` to find the path of the `lexbor` lib, which returned:

```
liblexbor.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/liblexbor.so.2
```

With the path found, I then ran the following two commands I recompiled using the same compilation command as the one seen above, but the same error message was shown:

```
[user@localhost]$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib64/liblexbor.so.2
[user@localhost]$ sudo ldconfig
```

I then tried a different approach to see if I could solve this issue by embedding the path into the compilation command, but this resulted in the same output:

```
gcc -L/lib64/ -liblexbor -std=c99 example.c -o example
```

**Please note:** before deciding to post this question, I consulted the following resources:

1. [usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l<nameOfTheLibrary>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary)
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007591/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lopencl

**Summary question:**

q1. How can this error be solved when trying to compile a C program using `lexbor` on CentOS 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying the library name incorrectly.  For a given library file named liblibrary.so, the correct option is -l library.  So you need to compile like this:

```
gcc example.c -llexbor -std=c99 -o example
```

Comment: thanks for your help, that solved it.