# Getting error bz2 module requires libbz2 >= 1.0.0 while compiling php 8.1.13

Tags: php, build, bzip2, php-8.1, bz2

I am trying to compile PHP with

```
./configure <other options> --with-bz2=/path_to_bzip2/bzip2/1.0.6
```

But when the build reaches bz2 it gives out below error

> ```
> ..
> checking for BZip2 support... yes
> checking for BZ2_bzerror in -lbz2... no
> configure: error: bz2 module requires libbz2 >= 1.0.0
>
> ./configure for php version 8.1.13 in php-8.1.13 did not succeed
> ```

I have exported path to bzip2 in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.
Also content of lib in bzip2

```
user@server [bzip2/1.0.6/lib]:ls
libbz2.a  libbz2.so.1.0  libbz2.so.1.0.6
```

Not sure why this error. I found at some forums that manually installing bzip2-devel before building PHP should resolve this. But that did not help

I tried with older version of PHP that earlier worked with same build script but those also getting into this error now. Not sure what has changed recently.

Comment: Distro? Version?

Comment: I am trying to install pho 8.1.13 on redhat 7

Answer (score 1):

This was finally resolved. And it was not related to bzip2. So for anyone facing similar issues here's the summary:
In config.log error was

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3
```

So, using answers from here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21647591/10091382

I tried to find if its able to find sqlite properly
Command used:

```
ld -lsqlite --verbose
```

The list displayed confirmed that its not getting the required .so files in the path its looking. So, placing the right files or pointing to right path would resolve this issue.