# gcc don't recognize the library linker -l as a command (on windows)

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, compilation

When i try to compile a program linking a library with gcc (on the recent 13.1.0), with a command like this:
`g++ -I/path/to/header -L/path/to/library -llibrary file.cpp`

the output tell me 'cannot find -llibrary: no such file or directory'

i already deleted and reinstalled gcc and tried to change the invocation order with the same result

Comment: What is the content of `/path/to/library/`? Is there any `liblibrary.a`/`.so` there?

Comment: The rules for how g++ maps the library name to a file name are varied and depend on the platform used (e.g. MinGW g++ uses different rules from linux g++). So explain what platform, what name you use and what filename you are trying to link with. I'm sure the answer is very simple but with the information given so far it impossible to say what mistake you made.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're assuming that `cannot find -llibrary` indicates that GCC is interpreting `-llibrary` as the name of an input file rather than as an `-l` option with the value `library`.

But actually, that's just GCC's weird way of saying "I couldn't match `library` to a library". After all, it checks in a number of places for a number of differently-named files (e.g. `liblibrary.a` but also `library.a`) so it has no way of knowing which of these filenames it was *supposed* to find.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710047/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lnameofthelibrary) for various reasons GCC might be unable to find the library.